# Why would there be a timer in the master closet?

Tags: electrical

I've been going to quite a few open houses lately, and I've noticed a strange trend.  In more than a few houses, I've noticed a timer high up on the wall in the master closet.

[image]

I've seen alarm control panels in the master closet before, but I can't fathom why a timer would be in there.  I'm thinking maybe it could be for landscape lighting, or a sprinkler system. I just can't understand why you would choose to install a control for those systems, in a second floor closet.  The first time I saw it, I didn't think anything of it (I have kids, so I understand the purpose of keeping things away from curious hands). After seeing it in more than a couple homes, I started to question the practice.

Anybody have any experience with this, that could shed some light on the purpose of it?

Comment: Have you been able to ask or trace it to an outlet or device?

Comment: Do the houses have lighting up in the eves around the perimeter? Maybe this is how they are timing the lights by using an existing branch circuit to save wire.

Comment: Wiring for the kids' internet runs in there, so it can be cut off at night ;^) (and mom and dad wonder why the kids' phone data use is so high...) (joking, probably.)

Comment: @BrownRedHawk Have not been able to trace it. Real estate agent has no clue, and homeowner is never around.

Comment: I would agree with some sort of exterior lights.  Have you seen if the timers have a manual override?

Comment: my votes are [soffit lights](http://designsenselighting.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Exterior-Soffit-Lighting.jpg), and/or outdoor christmas recpts. One sub-division in our area, every house is wired with a split recept under each front window (inside) for holiday candles. Top recpt switched by the timer circuit, bottom always on, the timers are usually next to the panel in the basement tho.  (Just curious are they really using Intermatic T101's or was that pic just for example?)

Comment: Did you notice what times are set on the timers? Any themes there? Night/day?

Comment: Another possibility I just thought of, If in an area that needs snow & Ice melting equipment on the roof it could be set to run at nights but I think lighting is more probable. If they are intermatic units like the one pictured there is a Manuel on off switch just below the time dial. Also taking note of the time they are set to turn on / off may help provide another clue.

Comment: I just talked to some of our residential service guys out in the shop.  They were unanimous, likely soffit or other security lighting and that it was likely added after the insulation/drywall phase.  I asked about ventilation or gutter heat, and the consensus was that would be better on a thermostat than timer, but then someone threw in there is always "Christmas".

Comment: @Tyson not sure the exact model timer, just grabbed a photo as an example.

Comment: I spend half my day talking about c-wires and insteon on the phone, but we still install/replace more Intermatic T101's than any other timer product.  They are loved for simplicity and loved by Gen X.

Comment: Any evidence they've used to the closet as a marijuana grow op and used the timer to control lights or such?

Answer (score 2):

Thus looks exactly like the timer we used to have hooked up to our water heater. We had it set to turn the water heater on at certain times right before we knew we would need hot water.